# How to read different types of data from file

Tags: c, arrays

I have a text file that contains string, int and double. Like this:

> Asher 10 14.5
>
> Julia  14 15.5

I need to read this data to 3 separate arrays. C don't have string array, so I need char array, int array and double array. My code:

```
const int num = 18; //number of data.txt lines
char col_one[15];
int col_two;
double col_three;
int c;
int numberArray[num];
char *nameArray[num];
double doubleArray[num];
int size = 0;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s %d %lf", &col_one, &col_two, &col_three);
        nameArray[size] = col_one;
        numberArray[size] = col_two;
        doubleArray[size] = col_three;
        size++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}


for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("%s \n" ,nameArray[i]);
}
```

But my code reads only first word and print it 18 times. How can I read string variable and put it into char array?

Comment: Try to check the return value of `fscanf`

Comment: `while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s %d %lf", &col_one, &col_two, &col_three);
        nameArray[size] = col_one;` -- > `while (fscanf(file, "%14s %d %lf", col_one, &col_two, &col_three)==3 && size < num){
        nameArray[size] = strdup(col_one);`

Comment: And `i < num;` --> `i < size;`

Comment: missing: `if (size >= num) break;`

Answer (score 3):

With

```
nameArray[size] = col_one;
```

you make *all* elements of `nameArray` point to the very same location. Which means it will seem that all strings are the same (and equal to the last string you read).

There are a few different solutions to this, but the one I recommend is to use a *structure* for the data, and then a single array for that structure. Then read directly into the structure itself, without using temporary variables or arrays of pointers.

Perhaps something like:

```
struct data
{
    char name[15];
    int int_value;
    double float_value;
};

struct data data_array[num];

...

while (fscanf(file, "%14s, %d %lf", data_array[size].name,
                                    &data_array[size].int_value,
                                    &data_array[size].float_value) == 3)
{
    ++size;
}
```

With the above code, you also solve another problem, that you read and discard the very first character of the file.